# SwipeRefresh indicator Stuck

Tags: android

I use a SwipeRefreshLayout to reload the content of a listview .But the indicator get stuck each time of loading .Is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: By "stuck" do you mean that the loading indicator never disappears? Or do you mean that it does not animate? Please provide more details.

Comment: it stucks the UI? is task completed but indicator doesn't hide? Need more details

Comment: I want to load(animate) the indicator till i got the response ..but what is the problem means initially it loads then it stuck's before i got the response from backend .

Comment: post some code to see what have you done

Comment: looks like you are running some tasks in UI tread.. What are you using  for your background task ? Loader ? Rx ? AsyncTask ?

Comment: Am using retrofit

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

The **`SwipeRefreshLayout`** will notify the listener each and every time the gesture is completed again; the listener is responsible for correctly determining when to actually initiate a refresh of its content. If the listener determines there should not be a refresh, it must call **`setRefreshing(false)`** to cancel any visual indication of a refresh. If an activity wishes to show just the progress animation, it should call setRefreshing(true). To disable the gesture and progress animation, call `setEnabled(false)` on the view.

**`setRefreshing`** 
  Notify the widget that refresh state has changed. Do not call this when refresh is triggered by a swipe gesture.

```
setRefreshing(true) //to show the refresh indicator.
setRefreshing(false) to remove the refresh indicator.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell your `SwipeRefreshLayout` to stop refreshing just like to tell it to start refreshing.

- `setRefreshing(true)` to show the refresh indicator.
- `setRefreshing(false)` to remove the refresh indicator.

If this does not help, please provide more details on your code.